# Transpose of a matrix element

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, matrix-elements

A matrix element is just a number. Now, If I have the following matrix element:

\begin{equation}
\newcommand\bra[1]{\left<{#1}\right|}
\newcommand\ket[1]{\left|{#1}\right>}
A = \bra{B}\bar{b}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{5}q\bar{q}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}b\ket{B} = f^{2}_{B}p_{B}^{2}
\end{equation}

where b and q are quarks fields.

Is it possible to take the transpose of both sides and say that

\begin{equation}
A = \bra{B}{b}^{T}\gamma_{5}^{T}(\gamma^{\mu})^{T}(\bar{q})^{T} q^{T}\gamma_{5}^{T}\gamma_{\mu}^{T}(\bar{b})^{T}\ket{B} = f^{2}_{B}p_{B}^{2}
\end{equation} ?

Therefore

\begin{equation}{b}^{T}\gamma_{5}^{T}(\gamma^{\mu})^{T}(\bar{q})^{T} q^{T}\gamma_{5}^{T}\gamma_{\mu}^{T}(\bar{b})^{T}\ = \bar{b}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{5}q\bar{q}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}b
\end{equation}

I am concerned about taking the transpose of the fermion fields because they are operators, not numbers.